# ggplot2 Load failure -

Tags: r, ggplot2, package

I am trying to load the ggplot2 package, and have installed the package from source as below;

```
> install.packages("S:/!DSG/! BJM1/Use-R!/Packages/packages-zip/ggplot2_0.9.3.1.zip",dep=TRUE)
inferring 'repos = NULL' from the file name
package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

I am pretty sure that any package dependencies have been resolved, but when I try to load the package. R returns the following error message.

```
> library(ggplot2)
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/jb04647/Documents/R/R-2.15.3/library/MASS/libs/i386/MASS.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.

In addition: Warning message:
  package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.0.0 
  Error: package/namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’
```

I have tried reinstalling the "MASS" package, but still get the same error.
On the it seems MASS requires R>3.0.0, while ggplot Requires≥2.14. 
No doubt other users have been running ggplot2 on R 2.14 or 2.15 so i do not think this is the issue.
sessionInfo details also attached.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Japanese_Japan.932  LC_CTYPE=Japanese_Japan.932    LC_MONETARY=Japanese_Japan.932 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Japanese_Japan.932    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plyr_1.8

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
Error in x[["Version"]] : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In FUN(c("colorspace", "dichromat", "digest", "grid", "gtable",  :
  DESCRIPTION file of package 'colorspace' is missing or broken
2: In FUN(c("colorspace", "dichromat", "digest", "grid", "gtable",  :
  DESCRIPTION file of package 'digest' is missing or broken
```

Has anyone else observed similar behaviour to this and found a solution?

Comment: What happens if you try again after `install.packages("MASS")`?

Comment: Yes - tried this, to no avail. Edited the original question.

Comment: Is there a reason that you must install ggplot2 from that zip file and not simply use `install.packages` for it as well?

Comment: Can you post your sessioninfo? All packages need to be rebuilt for R versions 3.0.0 and above

Comment: I am behind a firewall, so cant access the Cran repositories directly. sessionInfo() also posted...